# DFS-R pre-populated target folders STILL overwrite. How to avoid that?

Tags: windows-server-2003, filesystems, replication, dfs-r, preseed

I have 2 servers that I'm testing with, before I do this in live environment.  Server 2003 R2, fully patched.

I have 20 gig of data on server1 and I want to replicate that to a folder on server2. If I use robocopy to make an exact copy of the contents of the folder to be replicated from server1 to server2, and then link those folders in a DFS-R replication group I think it's supposed to compare the files on each side, and sync those that are different. Since I just copied them with "robocopy \server1\target \server2\target /SEC /MIR" they should be identical.

What actually happens is that DFS-R takes the data from server1 and paves over all the files in the server2 folder. It transfers all 20 gig of files over, which is specifically what I want to avoid.

-- Below is more info on my goal, but don't let it confuse answering the above --

Phase 2 of this test is to copy the data from \server2\target to \server2\target_new, stop DFS-R, rename target to target_old, and target_new to target, then restart DFS-R and have it not notice the folder got copied and renamed. This is because I'm going to take the data from X:\jobdocs and move it to Y:\ and mount Y:\ as a junction in the X:\ filesystem.  I can't change the drive letter or folder path or I break applications.  X:\jobdocs is being replicated across the WAN to another datacenter. I do NOT want to re-sync 500 gig of data just because I copied it locally to a different folder, so I'm trying to figure out how to keep DFS-R happy and ignorant of the change.

Answer (score 1):

with dfsr do the following to pre stage
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947726

Comment: I wonder how that works, since the stuff I'm doing results in the same CRC hash according to beyondcompare, but it still paves it anyway. I'm going to try just deleting DFSRPrivate folder on each side and seeing what that induces. I'm ASSURED they're identical right now, since DFS-R is what seeded itself.

Comment: not familiar with beyondcompare but dfsr uses more then just the information within a given file. So if beyondcompare just crc's the file the results will not be accurate